# Fullcalendar labels order differ in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar to display users in and out times.

I displayed the labels in the fullcalendar in the below order.
`First In`, `Duration`, `Last Out`. Everything works fine.
But in `Chrome Browser` the order of displaying labels differ for some dates.

**Initiating Fullcalendar**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
theme: true,
header: {
left: 'prev,today,next',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
contentHeight: 400,
editable: false,
weekends: true,
aspectRatio: 2,
events: arr//Array of labels First In, Duration, Last out
});
```

**Display in Firfox Browser** : Correct view
[image]

**Display in Chrome Browser** : Incorrect view
[image]

It should be in the given order but its not. Is there any solution for this issue.

Live preview URL at Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/8rxDGUUBJVRq1dja0Xm1?p=preview

Comment: Add `arr` details in question...Make jsfiddle also

Comment: Check working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/2313/) in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @Sarjan Desai How to attach the external js file in fiddle. As I have fullcalndar plugin in my local machine. I have to upload somewhere. Plz help me

Comment: Use [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) to add multiple file

Comment: @Sarjan Desai I have added demo url in my question. Plz check it

Comment: The display is correct in Edge and Safari (iPad) as well but different as described in Chrome.

Comment: A better option than the `alert` message telling people to look at February is to use the `month` option set to `1` (it is zero indexed to January).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to fullcalendar 2.4.0 or later and use the [eventOrder](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/) option.

> By default, FullCalendar decides that events with longer durations and earlier start times are sorted above other events. However, events often have the same exact start time and duration, which is especially true for all-day events. By default, when this happens, events are sorted alphabetically by title. `eventOrder` provides the ability to override this behavior.

There does not seem to be an equivalent option or documentation for fullcalendar 1.5.3. However, on a hunch, I tried adding some milliseconds to the start date. Chrome respects the start date ordering. See:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cM5Af5hVEh6vqSu6A5df?p=preview

Note: I also updated the data to use [eventSources](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/events_array/) to show how you do not need to specify the color over and over again.

Comment: But still  same issue in chrome. Have you checked this in chrome browser

Comment: Sorry, I did not press save in plnkr. Yes, I checked in Chrome. Check that the start date has some extra milliseconds `start: new Date(2015, 1, 02, 0, 0, 0, 1)`

Comment: Should be saved and frozen now. Please try the plnkr again.

Comment: My pleasure. Congrats on the yearling badge! I am getting closer to that one :)

Comment: Thanks and wish you the same